# How do I assign specific values to categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, data, visualization, categorical-data

I have a Pandas data frame with columns within a survey with the following categorical values -  "Increased, Decreased, Neutral". My question is how can I assign specific numerical values to these categorical values, namely +1 for Increased, -1 for Decreased and 0 for Neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Building on to @grov's answer, you can alternatively use `map` directly on the column like so:

```
df['col1_numerical'] = df['col1'].map({
    "Increased": 1,
    "Decreased": -1,
    "Neutral": 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to map from string values to specific numerical values is by using a Python dictionary as a lookup table. The lookup table can be used for each value in the column with `.apply(func)` on the column.

```
import pandas as pd
l = [{'col1':'Increased'},{'col1':'Decreased'},{'col1':'Neutral'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col1
0  Increased
1  Decreased
2    Neutral
```

Create mapping and apply:

```
value_map_d = {'Increased':1,'Neutral':0,'Decreased':-1}
df['col1_numerical'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: value_map_d.get(x))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col1  col1_numerical
0  Increased               1
1  Decreased              -1
2    Neutral               0
```

In the example above, I read the values column `col1` and write the numerical codes to a new column in the data frame called `col1_numerical`. The original column is dtype `object` and the output column is dtype `int64` because all the values retrieved in the value map are integers.